# Outwards spiral to matrix in Haskell

Tags: haskell, matrix

I'm trying to generate a matrix using an outwards spiral with a list as an input. Going to assume the list always has length that has a square route so it can fit in an NxN matrix.

```
myList :: [Char]
myList = "~~~~3~~2~~2~~~1~~2~~1~1~"
```

Given `myList` I'd expect the function to generate 5x5 matrix:

```
mkSpiralMatrix myList

> [["~","1","~","1","~"]
  ,["~","~","~","2","~"]
  ,["2","~","~","~","~"]
  ,["~","3","~","~","2"]
  ,["~","1","~","~","~"]]
```

Here is a visual representation of how the list was constructed using a spiral:

```
~ - 1 - ~ - 1 - ~
|
~   ~ - ~ - 2 - ~
|   |           |
2   ~   ~ - ~   ~
|   |       |   |
~   3 - ~ - ~   2
|               |
~ - 1 - ~ - ~ - ~
```

I've found [code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Spiral_matrix#Haskell) that I've played with trying to convert to my needs but it generates the matrix using inward spiral, and cant seem to convert it into outward spiral!

```
counts :: Int -> [Int]
counts = tail . reverse . concatMap (replicate 2) . enumFromTo 1

values :: Int -> [Int]
values = cycle . ((++) <$> map id <*> map negate) . (1 :) . (: [])

grade :: [Int] -> [Int]
grade = map snd . sort . flip zip [0..]

copies :: Int -> [Int]
copies = grade . scanl1 (+) . concatMap (uncurry replicate) . (zip <$> counts <*> values)

mkSpiralMatrix' :: Int -> [[Int]]
mkSpiralMatrix' = (<*>) take $ (.) <$> (map . take) <*> (iterate . drop) <*> copies

mkSprialMatrix' 5
> [[0 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,4]
  ,[15,16,17,18,5]
  ,[14,23,24,19,6]
  ,[13,22,21,20,7]
  ,[12,11,10, 9,8]]
```

But as you can see that code generates a matrix of NxN given N as an input. So it's not quite what I need but felt I could somehow use it.

Answer (score 1):

You're close. Consider this additional function (requires `sortOn` from `Data.List`):

```
sortUsing :: Ord a => [a] -> [b] -> [b]
sortUsing as = map snd . sortOn fst . zip as
```

Given an orderable list as a first argument, `sortUsing` will sort its second argument as though it were the first.

```
λ> sortUsing [5,1,3,2] "Khul"
"hluK"
```

Armed with this, you're but a single step from your goal. `sortUsing` is very easily converted to pointfree, too; that seems to be a goal of yours.

Comment: I've tried finding how I would use `sortUsing` but just not understanding, where you envision it's use?

Comment: @cmdv Let's say we have a small spiral `678 501 432` (generated by `copies`, approximately) and a string `"I am Khul"` to wrap into that spiral. `sortUsing [6,7,8,5,0,1,4,3,2] "I am Khul"` yields `"hulKI  ma"` (that space is actually two), which is the string spiralized as you wanted. [Looks better in 2D](https://pastebin.com/Dpx9U0fm).

Comment: ah I see what you are saying, now all I need to do is work out how to make my spiral go outwards no inwards like in the code I found.